# uitextview scrollRangeToVisible scroll from top to bottom everytime

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have two uitextview in storyboard. What I need is when the user type something in one textview should show the exact same data in another textview, also when the text is below the textview area it should automatically scroll up showing the last line. This is my code in uitextview delegate

```
<code>
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    self.textview2.text = textview.text;
    NSRange selection = self.textview2.selectedRange;

        [self.textview2 scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([self.textview2.text length], 0)];];

}
</code>
```

This code works but the problem is everytime it scrolls from top to bottom which irritates user. Any solution will be appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

Try this dude

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{

    self.textview2.text = textview.text;

    [self.textview2 scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, self.textview2.contentSize.height, self.textview2.contentSize.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                               animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both textView must have the viewController as delegate:

```
     self.textView1.delegate = self;
     self.textview2.delegate = self;
```

Then implement this methods in this way:

```
 -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
if ([scrollView isEqual:self.textview2])
{
     [self.textview2 scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([self.textview2.text length], 0)];

}
}

-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
  {

 if ([textView isEqual:self.textView1])
 {


self.textview2.text = textView.text;

[self.textview2 scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([self.textview2.text length], 0)];
}

}
```

The problem is the way textView work, when you make this:  self.textview2.text = textView.text; 
the text in the textView is first point to nil, (no text, contentOffSet point to 0.0), then the new text is pointing. The content change between zero and a big content (in fact bigger and bigger). the textContainer and textStorage of the text view are in charge of this work...

Comment: thank you for the help, but this is not my requirement. I need another textview to be scroll bottom when the user type and press return key in the first textview

Comment: @user1495387 Try this answer, please.

Comment: this is some how the same way i did, and i told you it scroll from top to bottom everytime i enter return key

Comment: What do you want to happen, when you press the return key, and how do you do the textView end editing ?

Comment: @user1495387 another question, both textView have the same dimensions and fonts ?

Comment: no both uitextview have different height. The original textview where they type works fine in ios7-ios8, it always show the bottom line of the text when they press return. I need to show the same thing in duplicate textview. textViewDidEndEditing works fine. I need to do it in textViewDidChange

Comment: @user1495387 I think I solved your problem, test my new answer please.

Comment: Hi Onik, I saw stil one problem, when the text are 20-30 lines long then it again starts scrolling from top to bottom

Comment: Wich font do you use ? I'm going to try to test.

Comment: also, i can't scroll up the textview2 to the top

Comment: I've just tried with:     self.textview2 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 120, 300, 90)]; and   self.textview2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30]; And I don`t have any problem.

Comment: Here is my screenshot
<img src="http://i58.tinypic.com/27zm9ah.png">, i am using autolayout

Comment: @user1495387 Ok, you can't scroll your textView2, of course. I thought you don't need. In a minute a fixit.

Comment: also, both uitextview have same font sizes but as i said after 20-30 lines, it again start scrolling from top , the old issue

Comment: yes, uitextview2 is not editable, its just userinteractive so that they can scroll it

Comment: so, you dont have any other idea?

Comment: @user1495387 I'm going to add to my answer a little explanation about the problem (with KVO you can see what happens), the problem is you need to test several ways in order to achieve the behavior you want. (I'm no sure at 100% what you want).

Comment: your code works fine until i press return key for 10-12 times but after that it again start scrolling from top to bottom

Comment: @user1495387 Yes, in this moment the jump between zero content and new content is too big.